# Error me deja compilar dependiendo de los valores del vector "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un merge sort y me da el error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`

Lo curioso es que cuando estoy intentando ordenar un vector que se vea de esta manera `{1,2,3,4}`, si funciona, pero cuando es un vector por ejemplo `{4,3,2,1}`, no funciona, y el error es cuando (para los que conocen el algoritmo merge sort) se compara un numero menor con uno mayor, por lo tanto cuando compare el 4 y el 3, no sabrá cuál de los dos es mayor por alguna razón.
A continuación el código.

```
/**
 *
 * @author marco
 */
public class MergeSort {
    public int [] mergesort(int [] A){
        if(A.length <= 1){
        return A;
        }
        else{
            int izq[];
            int der[];
        
            der = new int [A.length/2];
        
            if((A.length %2)==0){
            izq =new int[A.length/2];
            }else{
            izq = new int [(A.length/2+1)];
            }
        
        
            int i;
            for( i = 0; i<izq.length;++i){
            izq[i] = A[i];
         }
            
            int k=0;
            for(int j=i;j<A.length;++j){
            der[k]=A[j];
            ++k;
         }
        
            int [] Vec = unir(mergesort(izq),mergesort(der));
            return Vec;
      
    }           
    }
    
    
    
    public int [] unir(int []a, int []b){
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int [] c = new int [(a.length + b.length)];
        for(int k = 0; k <= c.length ; ++k){
           if(a[i] < b[j]){//Error cuando aqui compara un numero a[i]=2 y b[j]=3
                c[k]=a[i];
           
                ++i;
               
        } else{
            c[k] = b[j];
            ++j;
        }
        
        if(i==a.length){
            ++k;
            for(j=j;j<b.length;j++){
           c[k]=b[j];
           ++k;
            }
        }else if(i==a.length){
          ++k;
            for(i=i;i<a.length;i++){
            c[k]=a[i];
            ++k;
           
            }
       }
       }
        return c;
    }
}
```

///main

```
package com.mycompany.merge;

/**
*
* @author marco
*/
public class Merge {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       MergeSort x = new MergeSort();
       int [] s = {4,5,8,7};
       
       int []vecord = x.mergesort(s);
       
       for(int i=0;i<s.length; i++){
       System.out.print(vecord[i]+ "||");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿`k <= c.length`?  Quítale el igual al ciclo `for` por favor. En un array de longitud `c` los elementos van desde `0` hasta `c - 1`. Debería quedar `k < c.length`.

Comment: El error persiste, el error es porque en algún momento el array b llega vacío ya que el error se presenta en el if(a[i] < b[j]).

Comment: Ahora mismo no tengo tiempo para revisarlo a detalle, pero si te interesa, justo hace un tiempo implementé ese algoritmo. Checa este [gist](https://gist.github.com/JaimeMenendez/4abcacf5b5264801c69dd8c8ba06c2a0).

Comment: Muchas gracias, el error era bastante tonto, al final del metodo "Unir" se veía else if(i==a.length), cuando debía verse así else if(j==b.length)

Comment: En programación todo inicia con 0, teniendo en cuenta esto, en indice final siempre se le resta un uno